# Dice rolls and defining dmg_to_enemy

Tags: python, dice

I am having an issue with defining `dmg_to_enemy` in this function. I figured if I used [`random.randint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) to define `dmg_to_enemy` within the function, and then used return I would be able to print it outside of the function. Currently, when I run this code it returns `dmg_to_enemy is not defined`. I need to be able to define it so that I can use it for other functions. I am relatively new to coding and would like to know what I am doing wrong.

```
dwarf_class = "Thane"
def dice_rolls_combat(dwarf_class):  
    if dwarf_class == "Thane":
        dmg_to_enemy = random.randint(1, 8)
        return dmg_to_enemy
    elif dwarf_class == "Mekanik":
        dmg_to_enemy = random.randint(1, 5)
        return dmg_to_enemy
    elif dwarf_class == "Ancestrite":
        dmg_to_enemy = random.randint(1, 3)
        return dmg_to_enemy
    elif dwarf_class == "Prisoner":
        dmg_to_enemy = random.randint(1, 5)
        return dmg_to_enemy
    elif dwarf_class == "Civilian":
         dmg_to_enemy = random.randint(1, 4)
         return dmg_to_enemy
dice_rolls_combat(dwarf_class) #outside of function
print(dmg_to_enemy) # outside of the function
```

Comment: Change to `dmg_to_enemy = dice_rolls_combat(dwarf_class)` , use that to receive  the return value of your function

Comment: Or declare `dmg_to_enemy` global. (But better return and assign it.)

Comment: Can you share more of your program? There might be some improvements that could be made to its design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `dmg_to_enemy` is *local* in its parent function and does not exist outside of it. You seem partially aware of this as you have a single line `return dmg_to_enemy`, although its indentation level means it will only return a useful result when that condition fires (`dwarf_class == "Civilian"`). Decrease the indentation level to make that part work.

The other half is *using* that returned value, That is as simple as

```
dmg_to_enemy = dice_rolls_combat(dwarf_class)
```

although you can use any other variable name – this variable is unrelated to ones locally used elsewhere.